# How to cache a string value and use it in the future build in github action

Tags: github-actions

Because of specific requirements, I need to save a string value (the current SHA) and then retrieve this value in the future build, which will be initiated by a synchronization event.

I am trying this code but it's not working

```
  - name: Cache string value
    id: cache-string
    uses: actions/cache@v3
    with:
      path: microservices-results
      key: sha-${{ github.ref }}

  - name: Set string value
    run: echo "${{ MY STRING }}" > microservices-results
  - name: Retrieve string value
    run: echo "The string value is $(cat microservices-results)"
```

Could someone please suggest how to do so?

Comment: When would this *future build* be? Like in subsequent workflow runs? On the same branch?

Comment: @Azeem in subsequent workflow runs

Comment: For subsequent workflow runs, it should work with an `if` conditional which is missing in your workflow at the moment. If you could edit and update your question with a complete reproducible workflow then it would be helpful i.e. a complete working workflow that is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a file with this string as an artifact and then download it from another workflow.

For downloading, you can use:

- this actions [dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact)
- or [SDK](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/)

```
      - name: 'Download artifact'
        uses: actions/github-script@v3.1.0
        with:
          script: |
            var artifacts = await github.actions.listWorkflowRunArtifacts({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               run_id: ${{github.event.workflow_run.id }},
            });
            var matchArtifact = artifacts.data.artifacts.filter((artifact) => {
              return artifact.name == "pr"
            })[0];
            var download = await github.actions.downloadArtifact({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               artifact_id: matchArtifact.id,
               archive_format: 'zip',
            });
            var fs = require('fs');
            fs.writeFileSync('${{github.workspace}}/pr.zip', Buffer.from(download.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add checkout step.

```
 - uses: actions/checkout@v3
 

 - name: Set string value
    run: echo "${{ MY STRING }}" > microservices-results

 - name: Retrieve string value
    run: echo "The string value is $(cat microservices-results)"

 - name: Cache string value
    id: cache-string
    uses: actions/cache@v3
    with:
      path: microservices-results
      key: sha-${{ github.ref }}
```

it is work for me - as fact that build job for prepared building-tag was proceeded already